# nvidia GT 525m no screen found

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I'm a Dell XPS user with nvidia GT 525M with Optimus. When I installed nvidia I was greeted with blank screen. And the error in nvidia log was "Fatal error : No screen found". So after searching for the solutions I figured that I have to insert "BusID" in xorg.conf file. After rebooting I was again greeted with blank screen with error "Fatal error : screen already occupied".

I don't what exactly the problem is. Do I need to blacklist Intel inbuilt graphics to nvidia in my machine or anything else needs to be done? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is hybrid graphics. You need to follow the instructions on this site here to setup your late model XPS. Its for an XPS17 but should work for you...

http://www.cmdematos.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneric-on-dell-xps17-l702x.html